# Java: GC transparent background

Tags: java, swt

I am using GC (org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC) to combine some pictures into one image (using drawImage). The problem is that, by default GC has got white background. Is it possible to set background to transparent? Or any other solution to cut part from one picture and paste into second?

Comment: Is the image a jpg or a png or what?

Comment: PNG with transparency , when I set  gc background to example red, generaly it is copied ok, problem is to set gc background to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, GC is a pen, pen can't control canvas's transparency. It just can only draws something on canvas. So, GC can't manipulate image itself, just GC can draw something on Image.

However, You can directly control transparency data with ImageData API.
You should have to know what there is no advanced drawing API except setPixel(x, y, pixel), setAlpha(x, y, alpha) on ImageData.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Canvas with no background

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
```

And then you could (like in this [example](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency)) make one(or more) colors of the image transparent.

```
ImageData ideaData = new ImageData(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Idea.jpg"));
int whitePixel = ideaData.palette.getPixel(new RGB(255,255,255));
ideaData.transparentPixel = whitePixel;
Image transparentIdeaImage = new Image(display,ideaData);
```